# How to hide CSS class "feedflare" ? (There is no id="..." in the <div ...>)

Tags: javascript, css, html

Here is the code that I want to hide:

```
<div class="feedflare"><a href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/Maxkeisercom?a=6_7uX7znEdk:yCttzfYJmHw:yIl2AUoC8zA"><img border="0" src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/Maxkeisercom?d=yIl2AUoC8zA"></a> <a href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/Maxkeisercom?a=6_7uX7znEdk:yCttzfYJmHw:qj6IDK7rITs"><img border="0" src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/Maxkeisercom?d=qj6IDK7rITs"></a></div>
```

I don't know that much about coding and I don't know if this is possible...

And here is the example page: http://www.highbroadcast.com/2017/09/buy-gold-for-long-term-as-fiat-money-is.html

Here is the picture of elements that I want to hide:

[image: CLICK TO SEE SCREEN CAPTURE WITH MARKED ELEMENTS]

Comment: Are you the developer of the web site? Are you developing a browser extension? What's the context here? Sure, you can  hide it with JavaScript or CSS, but if this is, say, a WordPress site and you're the maintainer, you should probably do something different.

Comment: I want to make this element hidden in any of my posts... This is a Blogger site...

Answer (score 0):

If you can edit the HTML then the simplest way would be with inline CSS:

```
<div class="feedflare" style="display: none;">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `javascript` for this using the `class`,

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('feedflare')[0].style.display = 'none';
```

```html
<div class="feedflare"><a href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/Maxkeisercom?a=6_7uX7znEdk:yCttzfYJmHw:yIl2AUoC8zA"><img border="0" src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/Maxkeisercom?d=yIl2AUoC8zA"></a> <a href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/Maxkeisercom?a=6_7uX7znEdk:yCttzfYJmHw:qj6IDK7rITs"><img border="0" src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/Maxkeisercom?d=qj6IDK7rITs"></a></div>
```

Or, if you want `jquery` then,

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.feedflare').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="feedflare"><a href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/Maxkeisercom?a=6_7uX7znEdk:yCttzfYJmHw:yIl2AUoC8zA"><img border="0" src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/Maxkeisercom?d=yIl2AUoC8zA"></a> <a href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/Maxkeisercom?a=6_7uX7znEdk:yCttzfYJmHw:qj6IDK7rITs"><img border="0" src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/Maxkeisercom?d=qj6IDK7rITs"></a></div>
```